# Vue router link class binding active class

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a project where I try to render a sidebar which contains links to different pages. But these sidebar items need to be be styled differently when they are active. But I don't know how to get a boolean which contains this value. At the example I have the code that should determine if the router-link is active should be where I have written `true`

```
  <div class="mt-7">
      <router-link
        v-for="item in menuItems"
        :key="item.title"
        class="flex items-center pl-0 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-700 h-14"
        :class="{ 'bg-blue-300': true }"
        :to="item.link"
      >
        <div v-if="true" class="h-full w-1 bg-blue-700"></div>
        <img
          v-bind:src="require(`@/assets/img/sidebar/${item.icon}`)"
          v-bind:alt="item.icon"
          class="mr-3 w-4"
        />
        <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
      </router-link>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your class to the [`active-class`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class) prop of `router-link` component :

```
      <router-link
        v-for="item in menuItems"
        :key="item.title"
        class="flex items-center pl-0 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-700 h-14"
        active-class= "bg-blue-300"
        :to="item.link"
      >
```